# How to run "ANT" command in batch file through PHP?

Tags: php, ant, batch-file

My batch file includes following code,

```
cd C:\Ant
Ant
```

How can I execute this file in PHP.
I've tried everything including,
system();
exec();
passthru();

but none of these functions worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Batch files are no executables. Try

```
cmd /c your-batch-file.bat
```

Here cmd.exe is the executable. The /c options tells cmd to run the following command (here your batch file).

**Update:**

Without any PHP knowledge: the functions you are trying to use might be disabled due to [safe mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php).

It would be helpful (for any PHP developers) if you post the code line that tries to call the bat. Maybe you just missed a parameter or something like that.

Comment: No man it's not working, and I am trying to do it in PHP, but whenever I tried it ran in .bat file but when I go through PHP then it doesn't works.

Comment: Please extend your question with the snippet that tries to call the batch file as well as any error message or hint on the resulting behavior.

Comment: Hi, I would explain you in detail that what i have done and what i want to do.
I want to convert the Doc or Pdf or txt files into flashpaper, for this I am using Apache ANT and I was successful in converting those files manually through cmd, but now I want to do it through php, so that whenever a button is clicked the ANT command should run and the file gets converted. Now, please let me know in details which code would you like to view.
Thanks, 
-Avirat.

Comment: My bat file (ron.bat) contains,

cd C:\Ant
Ant

and this bat file is executed in my php file temp.php and the code is,

system('ron.bat');

I also tried using,

exec('ron.bat') and
passthru('ron.bat')

but when I use system() or passthru(); then it just prints the path in the browser and when I use exec() nothing happens and the page remains blank.